# Angular2 build failing with "Cannot find name 'document'"; other references fail to resolve as well

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have been working on adding Jasmine unit tests to my Angular 2 project and recently updated some NPM packages. I am seeing two different errors that I suspect are related (hence combining them in one question).

Firstly, I am getting a build error that prevents me from building my project. When I run >ng build in Angular-CLI, all the chunks appear to be created correctly, but I then get a wall of errors pointing to every place that I reference the global document or window variables. The errors look like this:

[image: example error]

Or, alternately, "Cannot find name 'window'." These references are not redlined in Visual Studio, and I've been using them for ages with no trouble, so I'm guessing that this has something to do with recently updating my version of Typescript?

Similarly, in my new test files, all the Jasmine references are redlined as unknown names.

[image: example of redlining in a jasmine test file]

Interestingly, the tests run without complaint; it's just that Visual Studio puts markup all over my test files. I've looked through the many SO questions about this problem and found that none of the solutions fix my problem.

Here's what my tsconfig.json looks like:

[image: tsconfig.json file]

I've checked that the TypeRoots path is correct and that those NPM modules are installed.

And my package.json:

[image: package.json file]

Comment: It should be `"lib": ["dom", ...]` in TS config.

Comment: There's no official support for TypeScript 2.2 with Angular 2, Angular 4 will support 2.2. Your app might still work, but it's just not supported. When you run `npm list --depth 0` does it give you any warnings/errors?

Comment: @Adam I get three errors: npm ERR! extraneous: karma-remap-istanbul@0.2.2 C:\PowerPay\Simplification\EvoNowHostedApp\EVONowHosted\Static\node_modules\karma-remap-istanbul
npm ERR! extraneous: utf8@2.1.0 C:\PowerPay\Simplification\EvoNowHostedApp\EVONowHosted\Static\node_modules\utf8
npm ERR! extraneous: webdriver-manager@10.2.5 C:\PowerPay\Simplification\EvoNowHostedApp\EVONowHosted\Static\node_modules\webdriver-manager

Comment: @estus Thank you! That solved my build failure! Do you think it's worthy of a proper answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Sure. Hope it will help somebody. Existing questions are often found by relevant error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript config should have

```
"lib": ["dom", ...]
```

in order for browser-specific globals to be used, including `document`.

In order for Jasmine globals to be used, `@types/jasmine` package has to be installed.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem nicely! In researching this answer, I also discovered that if I were to remove the lib property entirely from my tsconfig, the compiler would use a default set based on the fact that my target is es6; this set would include dom and es2016 as well as some other libraries. (See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: It never hurts to specify `lib` explicitly, just because it usually depends on applied polyfills, not on the target.